# Factory girl doesn't seem to like acts_as_singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a Rails application with **Factory girl** and the **Acts as singleton** plugin, and I get this error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Factory(:system)
NoMethodError: private method `new' called for #<Class:0x00000100b18ae0>
```

Is there a way to ask the factory to call the **.instance** method instead of **.new**?

Answer (score 2):

It seems impossible, but also look nonsence. A Factory is for create things, if you don't need that why to force the idea? Why not to use System.instance instead?

You can use System.instance( Factory.attributes_for(:system) ) if you want to force the idea.